# retrieve all occurrence of specific team id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have database table call team_members. In this table I save team_id and user_id. Something like below.

id  | team_id | user_id

1 | team_a. | user_1

2 | team_a  | user_2

3 | team_b  | user_3

4 | team_c  | user_4

Some thing like this. I want to find all occurrence with specific team_id.
I tried

**TeamMember.includes(team_id: params[:team_id])**
But this is not work. Can some one help me for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`includes()`is used for creating SQL joins (i.e., tying two models together via a foreign key). Since you are dealing with a single table, `where()` is what you want.

```
TeamMember.where(team_id: params[:team_id)
```

It will return an Array of all matching records (or [] if none).